# Cannot turn off only_full_group_by on Azure Database for MySql Server

Tags: mysql, azure, sql-mode, azure-mysql-database, azure-database-mysql

I'm using Azure Database for MySql Server, and when running a certain stored procedure, I get this error:

**In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'mydatabase.mytable.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

Now I know why I'm getting it, and I will fix the query, but it's a pretty massive query, and will take some time to do so. For now, as a temporary solution to get my clients working again, I'd like to set only_full_group_by to false. I understand that to set this globally, I need superuser priviledges, so I logged into Azure Portal, went to "Azure Database for MySQL server", went to "Server Parameters" looked for the "sql_mode" parameter, and was going to turn the "only_full_group_by" option off, but I saw it was already off. So I'm not sure why I am still getting the error.

I then tried turning it off for the session:

```
set session sql_mode='';
```

but I am STILL getting that error.

Is there no way to turn "only_full_group_by" off in Azure Database for MySql Server?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you turn it off???  Your query is the one that don't make sense.  The solution will be to fix your query.

Comment: I agree, it shouldn't be turned off. But as I explained, it was just a temporary measure until I could fix the enormous query.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I have disabled GroupBY in Azure, but error still throwing. Annoying. - did you have any luck sorting?

Comment: @spankymac to be honest i can't remember. It was about a year and a half ago. I think i never did figure it out, and ended up fixing my sql query :(